# How to set clearColor for presented view controller in iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I present a clearColor UIViewController over another UIViewController and it runs fine on iOS 7. But in iOS 8 I cannot display clearColor anymore. I've tried these things:

- set modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationCurrentContext
- set color of the window to clearColor

and none of the above works.

Does anyone have solution for my problem?

Comment: Did you have a look at `UIPresentationController`? They changed the presentation of view controllers in iOS8.

Comment: If you find a solution please post it here. It would also be interesting to know how you managed to integrate both approaches as UIPresentationController is not available on iOS 7.